# Dynamic radio button form react

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, forms, reactjs

I am building a dynamic form that fetches an entry from a db. The row results will render in a form and I have a component to render each entry in the form

The component of the `form-row`:

```
class Juego extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return(
            <tr>
                <td>{shortDate(this.props.juego.fecha)}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name={`apuesta[${this.props.juego.id}]`}  value="G" id={this.props.juego.id} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
                    <label>{this.props.juego.local}</label>
                    <span className="pull-right">{this.props.juego.spread_eq_local}</span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name={`apuesta[${this.props.juego.id}]`} value="E" id={this.props.juego.id} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
                    <label>Empate</label>
                    <span className="pull-right">{this.props.juego.spread_empate}</span>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name={`apuesta[${this.props.juego.id}]`} value="P" id={this.props.juego.id} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
                    <label>{this.props.juego.visitante}</label>
                    <span className="pull-right">{this.props.juego.spread_eq_visitante}</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name={`puntos[${this.props.juego.id}]`} id={this.props.juego.id} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

The rows are mapped this way:

```
juegosList=()=>{
    return (
        <div className="lista-juegos">

            <table className="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.juegos.map(jueg=><Juego juego={jueg}  key={jueg.id} handleChange={this.handleAddBet} addToState={this.addState}/>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And finally rendered on the main component:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className="juegos-form">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                {this.props.juegos.length===0?this.empty:this.juegosList()}
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Apostar</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}
```

I am trying to achieve this by passing the values of the `Juego` component into the state of the main component as an array:

```
apuestas:[
            {id,
            apuesta,
            puntos},
            {id,
            apuesta,
            puntos}
        ]
```

Something like this, but I am having trouble passing these values into the state of the main component.

Can anyone think of how to make this work or a better approach?

I am using 
NodeJS, React, Redux, Express and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is change the state from the `parent` component using event handled by the `child` component.

Your `parent` should look like:

```
class MainApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainInput
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And your `child` component:

```
class MainInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pQJvX03X2

You can see that the `state` changes dynamically when you start typing on the input.